# How to change background image in React depending on input value?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to change the background image of a site based on the input the user types in. For example, if the user types in New York or New York City or NYC, the background image changes to a picture of NYC.

Right now, I have a div tag with a class and in a CSS file, the background image is set to a url from the internet. I've figured out that you need to import the file that you want to use as a background image if you want to set the inline style in the .jsx file but I think this would be a tedious method since I have hundreds of images that I want to render based on the input. So without using jQuery (I saw another post similar to this question but in jQuery and I've read that using jQuery with React is not a great idea and I'm not even sure I could make it work with my React setup) how would you change the background image of a div depending on an input value?

```
function App() {

const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState('City');

function handleChange(event){
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

function handleKeyDown(event){
    
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){

      setHeadingText(name);
    }
  }

return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

        <input value={name} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} onChange={handleChange} type="search" placeholder="Search for a city"></input>
        
      </header>
      
    </div>
      
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of inline styles of CSS as one of the methods, I've re-written your code below.

```
function App() {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [headingText, setHeadingText] = useState('City');

function handleChange(event){
    setName(event.target.value);
 }
function handleSubmit(event){  
 setHeadingText(name)
  }

return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage:`url(${name}.jpg)` }}>
      <header className="App-header">
        <input value={name}  onChange={handleChange} type="search" placeholder="Search for a city"/>
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Enter</button>
      </header>
    </div>
      
  );
}
```

The backgroundImage URL, should be pointing to a particular file/directory in your project that contains the image, or a link to a jpg file that contains the image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried implementing this solution and it seems to not be working. I know it's not an issue about the path, because when I try to set the background image in the CSS file with the value of ${name}.jpg as the URL, it renders correctly. But when I try inline like this, I'm getting a white screen. I'm not sure why this is, but if you have any idea, I'd love to get more input. Thanks! Would I possibly have to install jQuery as a dependency and import it into my React project to use the $ symbol?

Comment: No, you don't need JQuery, frankly no one does in 2022. You have to be sure that the name variable is set to an image in the same directory the file is in. So if the image is in another folder you do something like "./../folderName" depending on how far it is in the folder Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites give API for searching wallpapers and background images that you can use. One of them is [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/). Please [register as a developer](https://unsplash.com/developers), make an application (or use Demo app) on that, and copy your ACCESS_KEY and past in code (YOUR_ACCESS_KEY) to send your request to Unsplash API and get wallpapers.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [backgroundUrl, setBackgroundUrl] = useState("");
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const searchBackground = () => {
    if (!searchInput) {
      alert("There is no any word to searching!");
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);

    // Send request to Unsplash API for searching your word and get wallpapers of that.
    axios
      .get("https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/", {
        params: {
          client_id: "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY",
          query: searchInput
        }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const results = res?.data?.results;
        const randomBackground =
          results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)];
        setBackgroundUrl(randomBackground.links.download);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .then(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  if (loading) return <div>Loading background...</div>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Please enter background title</h1>
      <input
        value={searchInput}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={searchBackground}>Search</button>

      <div style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
        {backgroundUrl && (
          <img src={backgroundUrl} alt="background" width={"100%"} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I have specific images in mind that I'd like to use so I don't think option would work for me.